# Web api return custom json format but how to convert to xml in c#

Tags: c#, json, xml

I need help.How to custom json format convert to xml. My json format is

```
{
  status : true;
  Code : 200;
  data : [
           {
             name :ram;
             age : 21;
           }
         ]
}
```

How to change XML format in c#

Answer (score 0):

use Newtonsoft.Json

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertJsonToXml.htm

This library allows you to convert between json and xml. From the page above:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
                          'status': 'true',
                          'Code': '200',
                          'data': [
                            {
                              'name': 'ram',
                              'age': '21'
                            }
                          ]
                        }";
        XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Root");
        Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<Root>
  <status>true</status>
  <Code>200</Code>
  <data>
    <name>ram</name>
    <age>21</age>
  </data>
</Root>
```

DotNetFiddle to see a working example:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/20vf4W